# run python script from network?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm looking for a way to execute blender, in background mode (`-b`) and giving a python script (`--python <filename>`) which is available in the network. For example :

```
blender.exe -b --python  \\Host\Dev\blender_setup.py
```

Currently Blender is looking for the script adding the current folder from which the `.bat` was executed (or C:\Windows if the batch file was in a network path). I've tried many syntaxes (//, \, \\, "\...", etc) and apparently I can't without mapping a network drive. I always get something like :

> OSError: Python file "**C:\Users\flavio\Desktop**\Host\Dev\blender_setup.py" could not be opened: No such file or directory

As you can see in bold, Blender is not looking in the right place

**EDIT** : Without mapping that network folder to a network drive and without simlinks. It would be too easy :)

Any clue ?

**EDIT 2** : Waow, actually any network paths, even for .blend file, are not working. This is very tricky for a renderfarm. The following paths (no matter the /, //, \\, \\\\ etc) will give the same result :

> blender.exe -b \\192.168.0.5\...\myFile.blend -a -x 1 -o

or

> blender.exe -b \\HOST\...\myFile.blend -a -x 1 -o

Will give the following error message :

> Warning: Unable to open 'C:\Users\flavio\Desktop\192.168.0.5...\myFile.blend': No such file or directory

(if the .bat file is on my Desktop)

Comment: Could that be a bug or a feature request to submit to the Blender Fundation ?

Comment: Apparently this was alreay an issue in ... 2009
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?207358-B-25-Network-paths

Damn

Comment: Basic UNC support is implemented: https://developer.blender.org/D298  This sounds like a bug/missing feature to me.

Comment: I don't know if I should report it, as it's listed in the TODO/UserInterface (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Todo/UserInterface)
> Implement generic system to handle cross platform paths, relative paths, network drives, shortcuts, stream input files, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's fixed on Blender 2.71 for windows.**

(As part of our network is still using XP we are stuck on 2.70a, and I didn't had the chance to test 2.71)